# TextView in customView

Tags: android, android-activity

I wanted to put a `TextView` into a `CustomView`. I had put it by using `findViewById`. That `TextView` I had directly inserted into the xml. Now i wanted to add text when a touch event is made.
Inside the `ViewActivity` I had put this.

```
public void getTextv(TextView tv)
    {
        tv1=tv;
    }
    int hit;
    public void setText()
    {    
             if(touch==true)
        tv1.setText(hit);
    }
```

Inside the main i had put `ViewActivity.getTexttv(tv);`

Then i got a error whenever text was added.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Is your error a nullpointerexception maybe?
shouldn't you set touch=true in getTextv(..)?

Answer (score 0):

tv.setText(String.valueOf(hit))

you should parse it to String firstly.

for the setText(int), the parameter should be a string resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tv.setText(hit+"");
```

As textview also takes an integer valuw which it thinks as an id from R.java file. So , you will get the error like  :

> Resourse id 0x02 was not found